# Photoshop and Illustrator image sizes

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop

I've saved a photo in Ps at 24x36 inches. When I try to bring it into Ai on a 24x36 artboard the picture is huge in comparison. Why is this?

Comment: what DPI was your Photoshop file and what DPI has your Illustrator project?

Comment: Hi Sergey it's 300. I even made the Ai file 300dpi. I resized the photo to match the Ai artboard then did an Export As. The file ended up slightly larger than Ps file I saved. I thought by re-sizing it would become smaller.

Comment: AI has no dpi setting, reread what the label says!

Comment: Ok 300ppi for both Ps and Ai

Comment: I was saving as JPG also

Comment: If you were using `Export As` in Photoshop to export your asset, DPI wasn't preserved (so it became 72). Make sure you use `Save As` to have the same DPI as in PS document.

Comment: Thanks Sergey I did a Save As and kept the ratio. What is the difference then between the two? My aim is to have my image printed. Is Save As ever not a good option when printing?

Comment: The other is meant for web and the other is not. 72 DPI is adobes way of saying not set (because they in their infinite wisdom forgot that a image really might have no meaningfull size conversion at all, like in web publishing. But in their defense they didnt think of any other industry than printing in the beginning anyway)

Comment: Oh and by the way, illustrator has no PPI settimg either. That setting does not change the document in any way. It only controls at what size pixel based effects are rendered. It does not apply to imports of any kind, or indeed 90% of functions you would use. Again reread what the option says.

Comment: I'll post my comment as the answer them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exporting an image for web (using the `Save for Web` command or commands from `Export...` submenu) will save a file in 72dpi: because for web dpi doesn't make any difference. To keep the dpi value simply save your file using the `Save As...` command.